# Python - efficiently find where something would land in a sorted list?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list:

```
x = ['c', 'a', 'e']
```

I can sort this list:

```
x_sorted = sorted(x)
```

`x_sorted` is now `['a', 'c', 'e']`

Now let's say I have a new variable `y = 'd'`

I want to find out where in `x_sorted` this new variable would fall. In this example the new variable `y` contains the string `'d'` so it would be placed as `['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']` in the index 2 of the list. I desire to find out this index number as efficiently as possible (since I have to repeat this process many times).

Here is a function I wrote which does the task very simply:

```
def f(x_sorted, y):
    new_list = x_sorted[:] + [y]
    return sorted(new_list).index(y)
```

This gives me the correct answer.

I am wondering if there is a better more efficient way of doing this, as `f` will be called 100,000+ times.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How often does `x` change, if ever?

Comment: @NPE `x` and `x_sorted` does not change, `y` will change a lot though. So basically I will call `f` with the same argument for `x_sorted` but different arguments for `y` many times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)

```
from bisect import bisect

l = ['a', 'c', 'e']

print(bisect(l,"d"))
2
```

To add it to the list:

```
from bisect import insort


l = ['a',"b", 'c', 'e']

insort(l, "d")
print(l)
insort(l, "f")
print(l)

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

If you want a faster insert you could use a [blist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/?) where maintaining a sorted list with insort is:

```
O(log**2 n)  vs  O(n)
```

from bisect import insort

```
from blist import blist

b = blist(["a", "b", "c", "e"])
insort(b, "f")
insort(b, "d")
print(b)
blist(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

There is also a [blist.sortedlist](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sortedlist.html#blist.sortedlist) list where you can use [.add](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sortedlist.html#blist.sortedlist.L.add):

```
from blist import sortedlist

l = ['b',"a", 'c', 'e']
b = sortedlist(l)

b.add("f")
print(b)
sortedlist(['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'])
```

There is also a [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) library that has a [sortedlist](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be something for this, would upvote but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @applecider You can certainly come back when you have enough :P

Comment: @Padraic ... What is the algo inside `insort` coz it's damn fast? (insertion sort?)

Comment: @applecider, no worries, there are variations like besect_left and bisect_right etc.. the docs list  the differences and provide some nice examples.

Comment: @BhargavRao `bisect.insort()` is basically a shortcut that combines `list.insert()` & `bisect.bisect()`. Bisect use a binary search algorithm, which is `O(log n)` i.e. very fast, but `list.insert()` is `O(n)` because of the way Python list is implemented. So `insort()` isn't that fast, actually.

Comment: @oxymor0n The last time I tried with a generic insertion sort algo and `insort` I got some really impressive timings from `insort` ...

Comment: @BhargavRao insort isn't a sorting algorithm. It'd be a mistake to compare it with an insertion sort algorithm.

Comment: @oxymor0n Yeah obvi ... I did not compare it with a sorting algo.  There is that part in insertion sort where ya hafta see all the elements from left to right in increasing order and then insert it there ... I used python funcs and `insort` to do that rather using the algo as they have explained it. -or- perhaps the py funcs had made it faster. But one obs was that using functions made it faster actually (though func calls make it slow) ... I would have loved to share the code I used, but unfortunately I formatted my hdd :( ... I'll just try to do that again and ping you back when it's done :)

Answer (score 2):

If `x` doesn't change, or changes infrequently, you can pre-sort it and then use binary search on the sorted list. This will incur `O(n logn)` cost for every sort plus `O(logn)` for every subsequent lookup.

If `x` changes a lot, you could use linear search:

```
>>> x = ['c', 'a', 'e']
>>> y = 'd'
>>> sum(y > el for el in x)
2
```

This has `O(n)` lookup complexity.

Answer (score 0):

That is surely not the efficient way as you demonstrated in your question, In that case you are sorting it each time and hence if you perform this action `m` times the complexity would be `O(m*n*log(m))`, So the preferred way is to sort it once and then simply iterate over the list to find the index, which could be done in `O(n)`, However the best approach would be to use Binary Search and Now your time complexity would get down to `O(log(n))`. Which is minimal complexity for such kind of problem.